# Problems with gitlabs gl-cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to build a pipeline in gitlab which is using their provided gl-cloudformation Template to deploy Infrastructure to aws:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/-/blob/master/aws/src/bin/gl-cloudformation

I am running into a problem with creating IAM roles since cloudformation is needing extra confirmation to deploy stacks which create IAM resources. Normally i would just run `aws create-stack --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM` but since i am useing their template i can't.
Anyone got any experience with running gitlab and cloudformation?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with that image. You must either use different CI Image or do not add custom name for the IAM resoucre (let the AWS generate name).